# Set checked datatable jquery looping not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable

I have code to checked data from ajax response in datatable, here it is:

```
kpi_id = jsonData.kpi_id;
 var table_kpi_list = $('#kpi_list').DataTable();
 $.each(kpi_id.split(","), function(i,e){
     table_kpi_list.column(1,{ search:'applied' } ).data().each(function(value, index) {
              if(value === e)
              {
                var rows = table_kpi_list.rows({ 'search': 'applied' }).nodes();
                $('input[type="checkbox"]', rows[index]).prop('checked', "checked");
              }
      });
});
```

I got no value(try to used `console.log`), then i try to make **alert** into it,and it **checked** (All value are shown). But when i remove alert,no rows checked.
Why and how to fix it? thanks

Comment: can u please explain clearly wht's the problem facing or else create a plunker so it will be easy to fix

Comment: via `alert` statement i think DOM is getting enough time to get rendered completely. Hence your `$(input[type...)` line of code is getting executed correctly. I will suggest you to put `setTimeout()` around your `$(input[type...)` code with say 200 milli sec delay and see if you get your code working.

Comment: thank u, it works perfectly @vijayP . i can't set this question is solved, cause you comment it.

Comment: may you set your answer in the answer form :) @vijayP

Comment: thanks @NikeYulistiaAngreni... `:)`!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am guessing via alert statement i think DOM is getting enough time to get rendered completely. Hence your `$(input[type...)` line of code is getting executed correctly. I will suggest you to put `setTimeout()` around your `$(input[type...)` code with say 200 milli sec delay and see if you get your code working. Your code can be altered as follows:

```
kpi_id = jsonData.kpi_id;
 var table_kpi_list = $('#kpi_list').DataTable();
 $.each(kpi_id.split(","), function(i,e){
     table_kpi_list.column(1,{ search:'applied' } ).data().each(function(value, index) {
        if(value === e)
        {
            var rows = table_kpi_list.rows({ 'search': 'applied' }).nodes();
            setTimeout(function(){
                $('input[type="checkbox"]', rows[index]).prop('checked', "checked");
            },200);
        }
    });
});
```